# How to delete database records in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin

I am new in VB.net, sql and even phpmyadmin gui. I want to delete records saved in my phpmyadmin but I got an error when executing sqlcommand's executenonquery()

This is my code used in VB.NET:

```
Public Sub RetrieveInfos(ByRef SQLStatement As String)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    With cmd
        .CommandText = SQLStatement
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = SQLConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()

    End With

    '--read the records in database in phpmyadmin gui---
    Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If myReader.Read Then
        lblName.Text = myReader.GetString(0)
        lblAge.Text = myReader.GetString(1)


    End If

    myReader.Close()
    SQLConnection.Close()
    MsgBox("Records Successfully Retrieved")
    SQLConnection.Dispose()
End Sub     
 Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
  Dim SQLStatement As String = "DELETE FROM patient WHERE 1"
        RetrieveInfos(SQLStatement)
 End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: phpmyadmin is a GUI tools for working with MySQL databases, not a database server in and of itself.

Comment: `I want to ... but I got an error` What's the error?

Comment: And are you sure the error came from the `executenonquery` and not the `executereader`?

Comment: the error is pointing to executenonquery. the error is InvalidOperationException was unhandled

Comment: what is the proper syntax on delete records? ex."DELETE FROM patient WHERE 1" but 1 should not be 1, I want to delete data without referencing with the recorded values. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To delete data from phpmyadmin, As specified in  [phpMyAdmin setting](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#AllowUserDropDatabase) that you need to edit in config.inc.php.

```
boolean $cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'] (line 503)

show a 'Drop database' link to normal users
```